# Double integral transformation - how to determine bounds of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

So here is the exact problem which i got stuck on.

> Evaluate
>   $$ I= \iint_A \sqrt{xy}\ dx\ dy  \quad\text{where $A$ is bounded by $y^2=2x$, $y^2=x$, $xy=1$, $xy=2$}$$

I am supposed to use the transformation $u=xy, v=\frac{y^2}{x}$.
Now I know that I will end up with $\iint \sqrt{u} \frac{1}{3v} du\ dv$.

So the bounds are supposed to be $\int_1^2 \int_1^2$ but I have no idea how were the bounds determined. Originally I assumed it was determined from the intersections of the $A$ but those are not $<1,2>$.

Also another thing I don't understand is why is the $G=\det|\cdot|$ used as $J =G^{-1}$ in the integral, when if we transform into polar coordinates we simply use the $J=G$ in  $\iint_B f(x,y)J\ dx\ dy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$A=\{(x,y): x\leq y^2\leq 2x,1\leq xy\leq 2\}=\{(x,y): 1\leq \frac{y^2}{x}\leq 2,1\leq xy\leq 2\}.$$
Moreover
$$dudv=\left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|dxdy$$
where
$$\left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|=\left|u_xv_y-u_yv_x\right|=|y(2y/x)-x(-y^2/x^2)|=\frac{3y^2}{x}=3v.$$
Hence, as you already remarked
$$ I= \iint_A \sqrt{xy}\ dx\ dy=\int_1^2 \int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt{u}}{3v} du\ dv=\left(\int_1^2\sqrt{u}du\right)\cdot \left(\int_1^2 \frac{1}{3v}\ dv\right).$$

Comment: Oh so i need to express the original boundaries as the transformation. Are there any more things to that? Like in case of different transformation? Or is it always done like this? Also do you have any idea about the reasoning behind the determinant, why is it different? (But thank you for that, i will mark it as the answer}

Comment: Yes, you have to rewrite the older domain using the new variables. As regards the determinant, I am not sure to have understood your point. Anyway I added a few details to my answer.

Comment: Well, when we transform some integral into polar coordinates. We calculate determinant with $rcos\phi$ and $rsin\phi$ and  we then have $\int \int f_{(r,\phi)}r\ dr\ d\phi$ . We use $r$ instead of $\frac{1}{r}$ in the integral. Why are these 2 transformations different?

Comment: Because $r=\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,\phi)}\right|$ and $1/r=\left|\frac{\partial(r,\phi)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|$